# TextBoxes in UpdatePanel are causing PageRequestManagerServerErrorException

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, updatepanel

I'm trying to create a page that has some information in databound labels with and edit button. When the edit button is clicked, the information is replaced with TextBoxes bound to the same data. The data can then be modified, saved back to the DB and the TextBoxes replaced with updated Labels.

To start with, and to keep things simple, all I have is an `UpdatePanel` with a `DataList` and two buttons: `EditButton` and `CancelButton` (`CancelButton` is hidden by default). The `DataList`'s `ItemTemplate` has two Panels: `ViewPanel` and `EditPanel` (`EditPanel` is hidden by default). When `EditButton` is clicked, I hide `EditButton` and the `DataList`'s `Items`' `ViewPanel`, and show `CancelButton` and the `DataList`'s `Items`' `EditPanel`.
Not a problem. Once this is done however, the `CancelButton` button will not work, throwing a `PageRequestManagerServerErrorException`.

Through some fiddling, I worked out this happens because there are databound text boxes on the `EditPanel`. If I don't bind data to the text boxes, everything works perfectly. Why doesn't this work?

Here's my code:

UpdatePanelTest.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="UpdatePanelTest.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebLetterViewer.UpdatePanelTest" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePartialRendering="true"></asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="AllLettersDataSource" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ORMSTestConnectionString %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Letters] WHERE ([id] = @id)">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="HiddenLetterID" DefaultValue="1" Name="id" PropertyName="Value" Type="Int32" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
    <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenLetterID" runat="server" Value="1" />
    <div>
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="false">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:DataList ID="LettersDataList" runat="server" DataSourceID="AllLettersDataSource">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Panel ID="ViewPanel" runat="server">
                            <h2>Data1:</h2>
                            <asp:Label ID="data1Label" runat="server" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" Height="100px" Text='<%# Eval("data1") %>' Width="500px" />
                            <h2>data2:</h2>
                            <asp:Label ID="data2Label" runat="server" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" Height="100px" Text='<%# Eval("data2") %>' Width="500px" />
                            <h2>data3:</h2>
                            <asp:Label ID="data3Label" runat="server" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" Height="100px" Text='<%# Eval("data3") %>' Width="500px" />
                        </asp:Panel>
                        <asp:Panel ID="EditPanel" runat="server" Visible="False">
                            <h2>data1:</h2>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="data1TextBox" runat="server" Height="100px" Text='<%# Eval("data1", "{0}") %>' TextMode="MultiLine" Width="500px"></asp:TextBox>
                            <h2>data2:</h2>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="data2TextBox" runat="server" Height="100px" Text='<%# Eval("data2", "{0}") %>' TextMode="MultiLine" Width="500px"></asp:TextBox>
                            <h2>data3:</h2>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="data3TextBox" runat="server" Height="100px" Text='<%# Eval("data3", "{0}") %>' TextMode="MultiLine" Width="500px"></asp:TextBox>
                        </asp:Panel>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:DataList>
                <asp:Button ID="EditButton" runat="server" onclick="EditButton_Click" Text="Edit" />
                <asp:Button ID="CancelButton" runat="server" onclick="CancelButton_Click" Text="Cancel" Visible="False" />
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

UpdatePanelTest.aspx.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace WebLetterViewer{
    public partial class UpdatePanelTest : System.Web.UI.Page{
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){
        }

        protected void EditButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
            foreach (DataListItem item in LettersDataList.Items){
                item.FindControl("ViewPanel").Visible = false;
                item.FindControl("EditPanel").Visible = true;
            }
            EditButton.Visible = false;
            CancelButton.Visible = true;
            UpdatePanel1.Update();
        }

        protected void CancelButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
            foreach (DataListItem item in LettersDataList.Items){
                item.FindControl("ViewPanel").Visible = true;
                item.FindControl("EditPanel").Visible = false;
            }
            EditButton.Visible = true;
            CancelButton.Visible = false;
            UpdatePanel1.Update();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does the exception have any message included? Perhaps some details or an innerException?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your `EditPanel` in a EditItemTemplate and use `Commands` , you are not using this control the way it was designed to be used:

[How to: Allow Users to Edit Items in DataList Web Server Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/90xwe9s3%28v=VS.80%29.aspx)

**Markup:**

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="AllLettersDataSource" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ORMSTestConnectionString %>"
        SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Letters] WHERE ([id] = @id)">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="HiddenLetterID" DefaultValue="1" Name="id" PropertyName="Value"
                Type="Int32" />
        </SelectParameters>
        <!--change this -->
        UpdateCommand="UPDATE [Categories] SET [CategoryName] = @CategoryName, [Description]
        = @Description WHERE [CategoryID] = @original_CategoryID">
        <UpdateParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="CategoryName" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Description" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_CategoryID" Type="Int32" />
        </UpdateParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
    <asp:DataList ID="LettersDataList" runat="server" DataSourceID="AllLettersDataSource"
        OnEditCommand="LettersDataList_EditCommand" OnCancelCommand="LettersDataList_CancelCommand"
        OnUpdateCommand="LettersDataList_UpdateCommand">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Panel ID="ViewPanel" runat="server">
                <h2>
                    Data1:</h2>
                <asp:Label ID="data1Label" runat="server" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" Height="100px"
                    Text='<%# Eval("data1") %>' Width="500px" />
                <h2>
                    data2:</h2>
                <asp:Label ID="data2Label" runat="server" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" Height="100px"
                    Text='<%# Eval("data2") %>' Width="500px" />
                <h2>
                    data3:</h2>
                <asp:Label ID="data3Label" runat="server" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" Height="100px"
                    Text='<%# Eval("data3") %>' Width="500px" />
            </asp:Panel>
            <asp:Button ID="EditButton" runat="server" CommandName="edit" Text="Edit" />
        </ItemTemplate>
        <EditItemTemplate>
            <asp:Panel ID="EditPanel" runat="server">
                <h2>
                    data1:</h2>
                <asp:TextBox ID="data1TextBox" runat="server" Height="100px" Text='<%# Eval("data1", "{0}") %>'
                    TextMode="MultiLine" Width="500px"></asp:TextBox>
                <h2>
                    data2:</h2>
                <asp:TextBox ID="data2TextBox" runat="server" Height="100px" Text='<%# Eval("data2", "{0}") %>'
                    TextMode="MultiLine" Width="500px"></asp:TextBox>
                <h2>
                    data3:</h2>
                <asp:TextBox ID="data3TextBox" runat="server" Height="100px" Text='<%# Eval("data3", "{0}") %>'
                    TextMode="MultiLine" Width="500px"></asp:TextBox>
            </asp:Panel>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CommandName="update">
                    Save
            </asp:LinkButton>
            &nbsp;
            <asp:Button ID="CancelButton" runat="server" CommandName="cancel" Text="Cancel" Visible="False" />
        </EditItemTemplate>
    </asp:DataList>
```

**Code-behind:**

```
    protected void LettersDataList_EditCommand(object source, DataListCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        LettersDataList.EditItemIndex = e.Item.ItemIndex;
        LettersDataList.DataBind();
    }

    protected void LettersDataList_CancelCommand(object source,
        DataListCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        LettersDataList.EditItemIndex = -1;
        LettersDataList.DataBind();
    }

    protected void LettersDataList_UpdateCommand(object source,
        DataListCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        //change this to your database needs

        //String categoryID =
        //     LettersDataList.DataKeys[e.Item.ItemIndex].ToString();
        //String categoryName =
        //     ((TextBox)e.Item.FindControl("textCategoryName")).Text;
        //String description =
        //     ((TextBox)e.Item.FindControl("textDescription")).Text;

        //SqlDataSource1.UpdateParameters["original_CategoryID"].DefaultValue
        //    = categoryID;
        //SqlDataSource1.UpdateParameters["categoryName"].DefaultValue
        //    = categoryName;
        //SqlDataSource1.UpdateParameters["Description"].DefaultValue
        //    = description;
        //SqlDataSource1.Update();

        LettersDataList.EditItemIndex = -1;
        LettersDataList.DataBind();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I thought I was doing something wrong and your answer helped a lot. I also found out that I had HTML in my text boxes and validation was stopping the form from submitting. In hindsight, that was the issue and so _technically_ this wasn't the answer to my problem, but as I said it helped a lot and also revealed the real issue to me.

Comment: Cool, glad it helped, I hadn't seen anyone use it that way before, I learned something new.